# VBA print labels with ODD starting numbers only

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I am trying to change a value in a cell to automatically display the next ODD number and print a copy of the active sheet after every odd iteration to a entered number. My code is below:

```
Sub EnterNumberLabels()

     Dim xCount As Variant
     Dim xScreen As Boolean
     Dim I As Long
     On Error Resume Next

 LInput:
     xCount = Application.InputBox("Enter the Number of Labels Needed:", "Kutools for Excel")
     If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
     If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Then
         MsgBox "Enter a Number of 1 or Greater", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
         GoTo LInput
     Else
         xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         For I = 1 To xCount
             ActiveSheet.Range("F17:G17").Value = "" & I
             ActiveSheet.PrintOut
         Next
         ActiveSheet.Range("F17:G17").ClearContents
         Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
     End If
 End Sub
```

This prints every page perfectly. The problem is I can't figure out how to make it change F17:G17 to ODD numbers only or only print the ODD number sheets.

This currently will print and change F17:G17 to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. to whatever number you enter for "Enter the Number of Labels Needed:" however I just need it to print 1,3,5, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go through the loop that prints the page, check if the page number is odd.

Replace

```
     For I = 1 To xCount
         ActiveSheet.Range("F17:G17").Value = "" & I
         ActiveSheet.PrintOut
     Next
```

with

```
For I = 1 To xCount
   If WorksheetFunction.IsOdd(I) Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("F17:G17").Value = "" & I
       ActiveSheet.PrintOut
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR I = 1 To xCount STEP 2
```

This will give you the values 1, 3 etc. without the even numbers.